# ElasticSearch: slow mapping creation when a lot of mappings exists

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index with a lot of mappings (about 14000). Creating new mapping takes > 10 seconds. Is there a way to speed up the creation of mapping in this case or ElasaticSearch is not designed for so many mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the mapping type citizen will eventually be removed from Elasticsearch (soft remove in ES 6 and hard remove in ES 7), i.e. you'll end up with an index having only a single mapping. You can read more about the reason behind this breaking change here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/index-type-parent-child-join-now-future-in-elasticsearch

If you have 14K mappings, odds are high that you have a high sparsity, which is what is probably causing the latency you're seeing when creating new mappings.